# How to build multiple ink contracts from a root folder?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo-contract

I have a simple parent folder and multiple contracts inside it in a simple structure as follows:

```
contracts
       |__contract1
       |__contract2
```

I add a root Cargo.toml file under `contracts` and with the following content:

```
[workspace]
members = [contract1, contract2]
```

If I call `cargo contract build` inside contract1 and contract2 it will work with no issues. If I call `cargo build` inside the root folder `contracts`, this will also work. However this is not what we want becuase it's not creating the ink contract bundles. If I call `cargo contract build` inside the root folder, it would complain:

> ERROR: Cannot infer the root project id

These contracts are independent and building them together is just for the sake of having a simple github workflow without the need to know which contracts we will maintain under the `contracts` folder at the github workflow level. Is this issue known? How can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/swanky-dapps/marketplace/issues/3

Answer (score 3):

This is currently a limitation of `cargo contract` and generally speaking currently there is no solution for what is asked. If `cargo contract` needs to be called in a folder other than where `Cargo.toml` is located in then the solution is to specify the manifest path explicitly. For example:

```
cargo contract build --manifest-path contracts/contract1/Cargo.toml
cargo contract build --manifest-path contracts/contract2/Cargo.toml
```

However for running the unit tests, there is no need to use `cargo contract` and if there is a root Cargo.toml file under `contracts` with the content as in the question, then the tests for both of the contracts can be run by simply calling `cargo test` under the `contracts` directory.